# MS Access Openform on Public Sub

Tags: vba

I want to create a single Public Sub on my module "BUTTONS" and call that Sub inside Button objects to open specific form on the current ID selected from a table list.

The right code (that works) was this one:

```
Private Sub Comando7_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenForm "DettaglioColore", , , "ID_Colore= '" & Me.ID_Colore & "'", , acDialog
End Sub
```

So, to let this code works with multiple buttons but with different form names and ID, inside my Public Module i wrote:

```
Public Sub CurrentRecord(NomeForm As String, ID, frm As Access.Form)
   DoCmd.OpenForm NomeForm, , , CStr(ID) & "= '" & frm.ID & "'", , acDialog
End Sub
```

Inside my button form:

```
Private Sub Comando7_Click()
   Call CurrentRecord("DettaglioColore", ID_Colore, Me)
End Sub
```

I don't know how to pass my "ID_Colore" inside the "Call CurrentRecord" Sub.
How can i reach this simple goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```vb
Public Sub CurrentRecord(NomeForm As String, ID, frm As Access.Form)
   DoCmd.OpenForm NomeForm, , , ID & "= '" & frm!ID_Colore.Value & "'", , acDialog
End Sub

Private Sub Comando7_Click()
   Call CurrentRecord("DettaglioColore", "ID_Colore", Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thanks for your comment. I still got the error "Invalid use of Property".

Comment: Your ID is named `ID_Colore`, I can see.